# ValueError: X.shape[1] = 8 should be equal to 1500, the number of features at training time

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn to train a machine learning model for sentiment analysis on persian text. Here is my code:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1500,
                             sublinear_tf=True,
                             use_idf=True,
                             stop_words=stop_words)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data).toarray()

le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(["pos", "neu", "neg"])
y = le.transform(data_labels)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

classifier_rbf = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=1, C=1)
classifier_rbf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier_rbf.predict(X_test)

with open('svm_rbf_classifier.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    _pickle.dump(y_pred, fid)

with open('tfidf_vectorizer.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    vectorizer = _pickle.load(fid)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print()
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

After train and test phases, I just want to load my vectorizer and classifier to predict Persian comments one by one. I wrote this piece of code for achieving this:

```
with open('tfidf_vectorizer.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    vectorizer = _pickle.load(fid)

with open('svm_rbf_classifier.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    classifier_rbf = _pickle.load(fid)

comment = 'من نسبت به نتایجی که تیم این روزا کسب میکنه نگرانم'
X = vectorizer.fit_transform([comment]).toarray()

predicted = classifier_rbf.predict(X)
print(predicted)
```

but when I try it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Projects/Sentiment/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    predicted = classifier_rbf.predict(X)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 576, in predict
    y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 325, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 478, in _validate_for_predict
    (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 8 should be equal to 1500, the number of features at training time
```

I don't understand this since I'm using the same vectorizer that I used for train and test. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't fit_transform your comments data, but only transform it. Change

```
X = vectorizer.fit_transform([comment]).toarray()
```

to

```
X = vectorizer.transform([comment]).toarray()
```